# MultiStringList in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, delphi

How can I do this the same way or almost the same as in Delphi because i know that .NET doesn't really have a real alternative to StringList like in Delphi.

MultiStringList splits a StringList in to N amount of sub stringlists.

**For example:**

You have a text and you would like to split it in to N amount of Lists. Or you have a situation where you would want to split a List in to many Sublists.

```
unit Multi;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TMultiStringList = class
  public
    type
      TFill = (mfiAdd, mfiClearBeforeFill);

      TMode = (
        mslTrim,        // Trim lines before add
        mslLower,       // Lower lines before add
        mslUpper,       // Upper lines before add
        mslAssign,      // Just use Assign()
        mslSpread);     // Spread text to the lists
  private
    FLength: Integer;
    FLists: TArray<TStringList>;
    function ValidArray(): Boolean;
    procedure BuildArray(const Length: Integer);
    procedure FreeArray();
    function GetList(const Index: Integer): TStringList;
  public
    constructor Create(const Length: Integer);
    destructor Destroy(); override;
    procedure LoadFromFile(const FileName: string; const Fill: TFill; const Mode: TMode);
    property ListCount: Integer read FLength;
    property Lists[const Index: Integer]: TStringList read GetList;
  end;

implementation

{ TMultiStringList }

procedure TMultiStringList.BuildArray(const Length: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(FLists, Length);
  for I := Low(FLists) to High(FLists) do
    FLists[I] := TStringList.Create();
end;

constructor TMultiStringList.Create(const Length: Integer);
begin
  FLength := Length;
  BuildArray(Length);
end;

destructor TMultiStringList.Destroy;
begin
  FreeArray();
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMultiStringList.FreeArray;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if (Length(FLists) > 0) then
  begin
    for I := Low(FLists) to High(FLists) do
    begin
      FLists[I].Free();
      FLists[I] := nil;
    end;
    SetLength(FLists, 0);
  end;
end;

function TMultiStringList.GetList(const Index: Integer): TStringList;
begin
  Result := FLists[Index];
end;
procedure TMultiStringList.LoadFromFile(const FileName: string; const Fill: TFill; const Mode: TMode);

  procedure HandleLoad(Callback: TProc<TStringList, string>);
  var
    List, Target: TStringList;
    I, J: Integer;
  begin
    List := TStringList.Create();
    try
      List.LoadFromFile(FileName);
      for I := Low(FLists) to High(FLists) do
      begin
        if (Fill = TFill.mfiClearBeforeFill) then
          FLists[I].Clear();

        for J := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
          Callback(FLists[I], List[J]);
      end;
    finally
      List.Free();
    end;
  end;

  procedure HandleAssign();
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    if (Fill = TFill.mfiClearBeforeFill) then
      FLists[0].Clear();

    FLists[0].LoadFromFile(FileName);

    for I := 1 to High(FLists) do
    begin
      if (Fill = TFill.mfiClearBeforeFill) then
        FLists[I].Clear();

      FLists[I].Assign(FLists[0]);
    end;
  end;

  procedure HandleSpread();
  var
    List: TStringList;
    I: Integer;
    ItemsPerList: Integer;
    ListIndex: Integer;
  begin
    if (Fill = TFill.mfiClearBeforeFill) then
    begin
      for I := Low(FLists) to High(FLists) do
        FLists[I].Clear();
    end;

    List := TStringList.Create();
    try
      List.LoadFromFile(FileName);

      ItemsPerList := (List.Count + FLength - 1) div FLength;

      for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
      begin
        FLists[I div ItemsPerList].Add(List[I]);
      end;
    finally
      List.Free();
    end;
  end;

begin
  if (not ValidArray()) then
    raise Exception.Create('Array incomplete!');

  case Mode of
    mslTrim : HandleLoad(
                     procedure(Target: TStringList; S: string)
                     begin
                       Target.Add(Trim(S));
                     end);

    mslLower     : HandleLoad(
                     procedure(Target: TStringList; S: string)
                     begin
                       Target.Add(LowerCase(S));
                     end);

    mslUpper     : HandleLoad(
                     procedure(Target: TStringList; S: string)
                     begin
                       Target.Add(UpperCase(S));
                     end);

    mslAssign    : HandleAssign();

    mslSpread    : HandleSpread();
  else
    raise ENotImplemented.Create('Mode not implemented!');
  end;
end;


function TMultiStringList.ValidArray: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Length(FLists) = FLength;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I'm reading this question as "Someone please re-write all my code for me". Not acceptable on StackOverflow.

Comment: @JerryDodge Not true. No one said 'please'.

Comment: can you explain more about what and how? (examples well be usefull)

Comment: @JerryDodge Not really Jerry. I asked how can this be done in .NET. I am sure it won't be the same. Delphi and .NET is like cake and butter. Many things can seem the same at first glance that don't mean they really are.

Comment: No matter what you intended, with that much code encapsulating a string list, just about anyone would assume you want someone to convert all of it to C# for you.

Comment: @Santos It just looks bad at first sight because your question is short and your code is long, even though you really did nothing wrong.

Comment: @Rotem I am moving to .NET and have no idea how it can be done. If you don't post code then people complain.

Comment: @SantosOliveira Again, I agree. Your code wasn't relevant to your question in this particular case, because there are better ways to approach this problem in .NET, but you had no way of knowing this.

Answer (score 3):

A 2 dimensional string [array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) should allow you to achieve similar functionality. And if you want to be able to dynamically add items to it, you could use a [`List<string[]>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Comment: So it can be done with 1/3 of the code that i used in Delphi?

Comment: .NET already has lots of built-in types and collections that allow you to represent various data structures. Depending on your requirements and what you are trying to achieve there might be more suitable data types.

Comment: Yes but this will split evenly the text file in to N amount of lines across the sub Lists.

Comment: So you wanna split a text into N amount of lines where each line represents a string? Checkout the [`.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method then.